# Pass String In same Activity

Tags: android, string

How can i Pass String in same activity? I have Many Buttons so i used getstring in open()???. All in same Activity.. in this activity i already used pass string using intent from another activity.

```
View view1 = findViewById(R.id.v1);
view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

            Bundle i = new Bundle();
            i.putString("key1", title1); // Key1
            i.putString("key2", link1); // Key2
            open();
        }
    });

View viewnowvideo= findViewById(R.id.tvnowvideo);
viewnowvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle i = new Bundle();
            i.putString("key1", title2); // Key1
            i.putString("key2", link2);  // Key2
            open();
             }
    });
}

private void open() {
Bundle i = new Bundle();
String titleok = i.getString("key1"); //// Key1

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    dialog.setTitle(titleok);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.open2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle i = new Bundle();
        String linkok = i.getString("key2"); //// Key2
        Uri location = Uri.parse(linkok);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
        intent.setPackage("com.dfgfdg.dfgdfg");
        startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is your issue now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `Bundle` argument to your `open()` method:

```
private void open(Bundle args) {
   String titleOk = args.getString("key1");
   ...
}
```

Comment: @nicopico                                                                                         Could I please ask. How then do you call the method open in the onClick cause it's no longer open(). Do I call it in this manner? - open(i.getString("key1"));

Comment: @Anon not sure I understood your question, but you can just pass the Bundle to the method: `open(i)`

Answer (score 3):

Just declare this line `String titleok = i.getString("key1"); //// Key1` at class level and you won't need to pass it in same activity again & again.

This is basically known as variable scope. If you declare any variable at class level it is available to all the methods & inner classes easily.

Example,

```
public class myClass
{
    private String hello="I am available to whole class";

    private void test()
    {
         System.out.println ( hello );
    }

    private class myInnerclass
    {
         private void innnerMethod()
         {
             System.out.println ( hello );  // direct accessible from outer class
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is usually better to keep variable scope where they are used, for clarity and efficiency. A variable like `hello` will stay in memory as long as the instance of `MyClass` exists

Comment: @nicopico, 100% agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in open method you can pass bundle and assign that bundle to your open method bundle.Hope This may help You

```
  class MainActivity extends Activity{
   Bundle bundle;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  bundle=new Bundle();   
  View view1 = findViewById(R.id.v1);
  view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {


        bundle.putString("key1", title1); // Key1
        bundle.putString("key2", link1); // Key2
        open();
    }
   });

 View viewnowvideo= findViewById(R.id.tvnowvideo);
  viewnowvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {

        bundle.putString("key1", title2); // Key1
        bundle.putString("key2", link2);  // Key2
        open();
         }
});
}

 private void open() {

String titleok = bundle.getString("key1"); //// Key1

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setTitle(titleok);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.open2);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    String linkok = bundle.getString("key2"); //// Key2
    Uri location = Uri.parse(linkok);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
    intent.setPackage("com.dfgfdg.dfgdfg");
    startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Not work..I dont know why... There is any way to pass string?

Comment: @user1901994 you can use a String argument instead of a Bundle if this is all you need

Comment: then don't use bundle,just pass the string argument like open(title2,link2)

Comment: Problem i want use this same open() in many buttons, with different String value

Comment: Declare a bundle globally with null like this Bundle bundle=new Bundle(); then onclicklistener putString("KEY1",title1)

Comment: I have make changes to the previous coding hope this will work for  you